# What makes an alternating-current electric motor rotate in a preferred direction?

Tags: ac, motor-controller

Intuitively, from a position of ignorance about the design of AC motors, I would have expected the direction of rotation to vary randomly with each start-up. This appears to be the case for motors driving the turntable in microwave ovens. However, for most applications, it is important that rotation is only in a designated direction. How is this achieved?

Comment: There are many types of AC motors, and within the types there are different ways of achieving this.  I would start with the [Wikipedia article on AC motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor), then return here with more specific questions if you are still not clear.

Answer (score 3):

AC motors need more than one phase in order to start up in a particular direction.

With 3-phase motors, the direction of rotation is determined by the order of the phase connections.

With single-phase motors, there are a number of ways to create a second phase:

- shaded pole - (used primarily in small motors) part of each stator pole is wrapped with a ring of copper (a shorted turn) that causes the phase of the magnetic field to be shifted.
- capacitor-start - a second winding is energized through a capacitor (which shifts the phase), but is disabled once the motor is up to speed by a centrifugal switch. Once the motor is running, a single phase will keep it going by itself.
- capacitor run - a second winding is energized at all times through a capacitor, which shifts the phase. Some motors of this type are symmetrical and can be reversed by swapping the direct-connected and capacitor-connected windings.

Answer (score 2):

The motor in a microwave oven is a synchronous machine. As it has only one stator winding, and the rotor being a permanent magnet, there isn't a preferred direction. Once the motor runs, the direction it started "settles" because of the rotating fields of the stator and the moving rotor produce a torque in always the same direction.

---

Universal motors as in a power drill however have **two** windings put in series. One for the rotor, and one for the stator. If you reverse one of them, the running direction changes.

That's why it also works on AC. During an AC cycle, the current direction always changes for both windings at the same time, so the resulting torque is always the same direction. This works from standstill.

Comment: f-me, you're right, my cup of tea does go both ways in the microwave.